# R recursive function call that works without stating arguments to function

Tags: r, recursion, arguments, call

The following simple recursion finds duplicated elements in a vector. It's taken from *chapter 2 Functional Programming in R: Advanced Statistical Programming for Data Science, Analysis and Finance* by Thomas Mailund. I wonder why it works when we call `rest` inside the function as it is calling a function without stating arguments.

Usually this would just return the function definition, but in the recursive function we don't need to and I wondered why.

I can see how this would work if we replaced `rest` in the function directly with `find_duplicates(x, i + 1)`, but I am struggling to see why it works calling just the name which the function is attached to.

E.g if we define `f<- function (x) x` and call `f` it just returns the code `function (x) x`.

```
find_duplicates <- function(x, i = 1) {
    if (i >= length(x)) return(c())
   rest <- find_duplicates(x, i + 1)
    if (x[i] == x[i + 1]) c(i, rest)
    else rest
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rest` is not a function, it's the output of the function `find_duplicates` given arguments `x` and `i+1`.

So indeed it's the same to type `rest` or `find_duplicates(x, i + 1)` in the `if` clause, they're both values, not functions.

Comment: Thanks, I now get why it works placing rest in for find_duplicates(x,i+1), in essence it calls find_duplicates(x,i+1) where x and i are found in the function environment.  However I don't get the output from placing print in the function as you mention.   Take the case x=c(1,1,1)  then at i=1 we get c(1, find_duplicates(x,2))  at this point find_duplicates(x,2) is implicitly defined, then it runs again and we get c(1,2, find_duplicates(x,3)) which is c(1,2) as find_duplicates(x,3)=c()).

Comment: If we place print(rest) where you said  it prints the duplicates in the sequence but in reverse (seems to start at the final iteration of i and work back). Does R first evaluate where a recursion will end and work backwards in the evaluation, whereas the logic I stated did it the other way?

Comment: I deleted this comment as I finally thought it added confusion. It's normal that the values are printed in reverse. Think of it this way: the first call is the last to finish, and the print statement is AFTER the recursive call. Your first call will get to the `print` statement only after the second call is completed (so after it has printed).

Comment: So the function calls the first recursion first (which includes this print statement) which it doesn't evaluate (and can't anyway) until it gets all the way to the final recursion, the last call to the function which can be evaluated and is, so it prints the last part of the recursion first, then peels back once and executes the stored call which includes the print, and then back to the start? I think I get it. The logic is pretty simple but it is always a bit of a mystery inferring how R works by reverse engineering (literally here).

Comment: It's not R It's recursion :). It takes some time to wrap one's head around it. Your description of how it works is correct